# Meteor.js on Android - can't display contact photo uri. Getting "Not allowed to load local resource: content://com.android.contacts/..."

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, contacts, cordova-plugins

I want to display the contact image next to its details. I can get all the details and photos URIs from the contacts plugin but keep getting this error when trying to use the photo URI as the img src attribute:

> Not allowed to load local resource:
>   content://com.android.contacts/contacts/123/photo

I'm using Meteor.js 1.1 and added `App.accessRule("content://*")` to my mobile-config.js `(App.accessRule("*")` didn't work as well).

Using window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL I can get the fileEntry for the file but it has the same path information:

```
{
     "isFile":true
    ,"isDirectory":false
    ,"name":"photo"
    ,"fullPath":"\/com.android.contacts\/contacts\/123\/photo"
    ,"filesystemName":"content"
    ,"filesystem":1
    ,"nativeURL":"content:\/\/com.android.contacts\/contacts\/123\/photo"
}
```

I don't know what am I doing wrong - please help!

### Update

I've tried loading contact images using a simple cordova project and it works fine.

This seems to be an open issue with Meteor https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/3799

No workaround in sight...